# How do I filter out dulplicate rows in my SQL query

Tags: t-sql

My initial query (select * from tbl order by employee_id) returns the following:

```
employee_name   Dept_Code   Supervisor          Date
John              99213     Mike              2013-01-10
John              99213     Dan               2013-12-13
John              99214     Kelly             2013-12-10
John              99215     Tammy             2013-09-09
Nancy             99244     Roy               2013-05-07
Nancy             99213     Cory              2013-04-05
Nancy             99214     Donald            2013-04-19
Nancy             99243     William           2013-07-01
Nancy             99244     Nick              2013-06-03
Rich              99203     Amber             2013-04-12
Dawn              99213     Nelson            2013-11-06
Rob               99213     Henrey            2013-08-01
Lewis             99213     Eric              2013-12-02
Alex              99203     Chris             2013-08-08
Alex              99243     Frank             2013-09-25
Bing              67228     Paula             2013-12-17
Bing              92225     Paula             2013-11-19
```

I only want to return the employee_name, Dept_Code and Supervisor with the max(Date). However, when I run the below. My result are the same.

```
SELECT  employee_namd ,
        Dept_Code ,
        Supervisor ,
        MAX(Date) AS 'Date'
FROM    tbl
GROUP BY employee_name ,
        Dept_Code ,
        Supervisor
ORDER BY employee_name
```

**I would like to see only:**

```
employee_name   Dept_Code   Supervisor         Date
John              99213      Dan              2013-12-13
Nancy             99243      William          2013-07-01
Rich              99203      Amber            2013-04-12
Dawn              99213      Nelson           2013-11-06
Rob               99213      Henrey           2013-08-01
Lewis             99213      Eric             2013-12-02
Alex              99243      Frank            2013-09-25
Bing              67228      Paula            2013-12-17
```

Answer (score 1):

```
;WITH Latest
AS
 (
  SELECT *,
     RN =  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY employee_name ORDER BY [Date] DESC)
  FROM TABLE_NAME
 )
SELECT employee_name   
      ,Dept_Code   
      ,Supervisor  
      ,[Date]
FROM Latest
WHERE RN = 1
```